# Python: Dictionary with values higher than the average value

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I am trying to write a program that reads two textfiles (box_a and box_b). These files have the license plate number and the time this car passes two different speed cameras. The format in the files is like this: `6TKJ777, 2018-02-09 09:13:22`. I would like the program to calculate the average speed (see `avg_speed` in the code below) between these cameras (based on the time of the passings on box_a and box_b, and the distance from the variable `distance` below.). The cars with an `avg_speed` above the speed limit (the variable `speed_limit` below) should be added to a dictionary where registration number is key, and `avg_speed` and the time the car passes box_a as a `tuple`. This dictionary only contains cars that have broken the speed limit. I seem to have got stuck. The code below probably have several issues, but the latest error is name `license_` is not defined. Any ideas?

```py
from datetime import datetime
date_format = ' %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

def file_to_dictionary(file):
    filename = file
    filename = open(file, 'r')
    readings = []
    for line in filename:
        line = line.strip('\n')
        reg = line.split(',')
        readings.append(reg)
    filename.close()
    dictionary = dict(readings)
    for key in dictionary:
        print(key, ' : ', dictionary[key])
    return dictionary

def list_speeders():
    filename_a = "box_a.txt"
    filename_b = "box_b.txt"
    speed_limit = 60
    distance = 5

    mydict= {license_:(avg_speed,b_time)}

    dict_a = file_to_dictionary(filename_a)
    dict_b = file_to_dictionary(filename_b)
    a_time = dict_a[license_]
    b_time = dict_b[license_]
    
    avg_speed=round(distance/(((datetime.strptime(b_time, date_format) - datetime.strptime(a_time, date_format)).total_seconds())/3600),3)
    
    for line in dict_a:
        if avg_speed > speed_limit:
            mydict[license_]=avg_speed
        
    print(mydict)

list_speeders()
```

Comment: It's exactly what the error says. The variable `license_` is not defined. If it was meant to be text, then use `"license_"`.

Comment: I think you meant to write: `mydict = {}`. Now you will see the next problem with your code.

Comment: Seems like list_speeders changes to do things to one individual license plate halfway through. a_time is supposed to be for one single license plate.

Comment: @JollyJoker, that is correct. I wrote it first to print output on just one license plate (based on user input). Now I am trying to expand it to check multiple license plates - and this is a bit of a struggle

Comment: You are having problems with your process of software development, so not a good fit with stackoverflow. You should write your new program in small steps: You seem to have read in the contents of the files. Now you should investigate each license plate from `dict_a`, ie see if it is also present in `dict_b`. Then you can go on to calculate the speed.

Answer (score 0):

The code is less cumbersome if you convert the date and time to a timestamp when you first build the dictionaries. Then it's simple:

```
from datetime import datetime

date_format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
speed_limit = 60
distance = 5

def to_dictionary(filenames):
    alldicts = tuple()
    for filename in filenames:
        d = {}
        with open(filename, encoding='utf-8') as infile:
            for line in infile:
                reg, dt = line.split(',')
                d[reg] = datetime.strptime(dt.strip(), date_format).timestamp()
        alldicts += (d, )
    return alldicts

box_a, box_b = to_dictionary(('box_a.txt', 'box_b.txt'))

speeders = {}

for k, va in box_a.items():
    if (vb := box_b.get(k)):
        if (average_speed := distance / abs(va-vb) * 3600) > speed_limit:
            speeders[k] = average_speed

print(speeders)
```